# Own buttons in jquery dialog not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an application with a lot of textareas and one button for each textarea.
If the user edits content, it will be saved into the database. 
When clicking on the button, a dialog opens and displays all earlier versions of the content of that specific area.
This is loaded by .html() in that dialog.
Now I want a button on each earlier version in that dialog. When clicking on that button, this earlier version should copied to the textarea of the "main" site.

My problem: I could not get the buttons working, not even with an alert.
Where am I wrong?

Open the dialog, working:

```
$( ".historydialog" ).click(function( event ) {
    var idhist = $(this).attr('id');
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $.get( "getLangHist.php", { idhist: idhist }, function( data ) {
                $( "#divInDialog" ).html( data );
            }); 
        },
        maxWidth:600,
        maxHeight: 500,
        width: 600,
        height: 500
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The button in the dialog:

```
<button id="history-{id}" class="historybutton">
```

Button action, not working:

```
$(".historybutton").click(function( event ) {
    alert('test');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you're adding the content to the dialog using `.html()`

This would imply that you're dynamically adding the content to the `DOM`

If this is the case, then you can change your `click` handler to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.historybutton', function(){
  alert('test');
});
```

This will bind the `click` handler to dynamically added content.

As a side-note. Rather than pepper your controls with delimited ID's, like `"history-{id}"` you could use `data-` attributes. It's far more obvious when looking through the code too.

So your button would be:

`<button data-history-id="123" class="historybutton">history</button>`

You can then access this using the `data` method in jQuery

`var hId = $('.historybutton').data('history-id')`;

Comment: This works fine, thanks. Also thanks for the "data-" tip. It is sure more readable.

Comment: You're welcome - and yep, data tags are perfect for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("body").delegate('.historybutton','click',function( event ) {
    alert('test');
});
```